# Selecting the right object while iterating through multiple instances. - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have seven different `assignment` objects. I'm currently iterating through each instance and then I iterating through the `users` of each assignment. I'm trying to `designate` the users to the assignment. I have a has_many through table that assigns the user to the assignment. But, my problem right now is that it keeps selecting the first assignment when I'm trying to select the fourth assignment. The way I'm iterating with the HTML is wrong but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing? Here is my HTML.

### HTML:

```
<div class="assignments">
  <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to assignment.name, account_assignment_path(assignment) %></li>
      <%= link_to "designate Worker", "#designate", class: "button", data: { designate_worker: "" } %>
      <div id="workers-modal", class="modal--worker hidden">
        <% @account.account_workers.each do |worker| %>
            <ul>
              <li><%= link_to worker.name, designate_account_assignment_path(assignment, user_id: worker.id) %></li>
            </ul>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm iterating through all the assignment on the current account. Then, I'm iterating through all the users on the current account. Then, I'm trying to select the particular assignment by the id and the user by the id and create a relationship between the two, But from the UI I can't select any `assignment` but the first one. I think this has something to do with the way I'm iterating but I don't know for sure.

### Controller:

```
  def designate
    designated_user = current_account.users.find_by(id: params[:user_id])
    membership = designated_user.assignment_relationships.find_or_create_by(assignment_id: params[:id])

    membership.update!(designated: true)
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully designated the user"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

As you can see. The second line in the method looks for the assignment_id with the params[:id]. Right now it only comes in as :id => "1", when I'm trying to get :id => "2" or "4"

Let me know if you need to see any other code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to start a new list for each assignment and each worker. If you inspect the view, do you see each of the assignments with different ids? Try amending the view so the unordered list tags are outside the each loop:

```
<div class="assignments">
  <ul>
    <% @assignments.each do |assignment| %>
      <li><%= link_to assignment.name, account_assignment_path(assignment) %></li>
      <%= link_to "designate Worker", "#designate", class: "button", data: { designate_worker: "" } %>
      <div id="workers-modal", class="modal--worker hidden">
        <ul>
          <% @account.account_workers.each do |worker| %>       
            <li><%= link_to worker.name, designate_account_assignment_path(assignment, user_id: worker.id) %></li>       
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```